# Ktor dependency

Tags: maven, ktor

For context, I am new to Kotlin and Ktor.

This is Application.kt file. The problem is with install, Locations, Authentication, ContentNegotiation. I'm unable to import them even though I have added their maven dependency.

The pom.xml file is added below.

```
import com.userTodo.auth.JwtService
import com.userTodo.auth.MySession
import com.userTodo.auth.hash
import com.userTodo.repository.DatabaseFactory
import com.userTodo.repository.TodoRepository
import com.userTodo.repository.UserRepository
import com.userTodo.routes.todos
import com.userTodo.routes.users
import io.ktor.http.*
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.response.*
import io.ktor.server.request.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.auth.*
import io.ktor.server.auth.jwt.*


fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)

fun Application.module() {
    install(Locations) {
    }

    DatabaseFactory.init()
    val userDb = UserRepository()
    val todoDb = TodoRepository()
    val jwt = JwtService()
    val hashFunction = {s:String -> hash(s)}

    install(Sessions) {
        cookie<MySession>("MY_SESSION") {
            cookie.extensions["SameSite"] = "lax"
        }
    }

    install(Authentication) {
        jwt("jwt") {

        }
    }

    install(ContentNegotiation) {
        json()
    }


    routing {
        users(userDb,todoDb,jwt,hashFunction)
        todos(todoDb,userDb)
    }
}

const val API_VERSION = "/v1"
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.userTodo</groupId>
    <artifactId>com-usertodo-user-todo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>com.userTodo.user_todo</name>
    <description>com.userTodo.user_todo</description>
    <properties>
        <ktor_version>2.0.0</ktor_version>
        <kotlin.code.style>official</kotlin.code.style>
        <kotlin_version>1.6.21</kotlin_version>
        <logback_version>1.2.11</logback_version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <kotlin.compiler.incremental>true</kotlin.compiler.incremental>
        <main.class>com.userTodo.ApplicationKt</main.class>
        <main.class>io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain</main.class>
    </properties>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>ktor_eap</id>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/ktor/eap</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>ktor-eap</id>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/kotlin/p/kotlin/dev</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-core-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-netty-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-tests-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor_version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-auth</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin_version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
            <artifactId>exposed-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.38.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
            <artifactId>exposed-dao</artifactId>
            <version>0.38.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
            <artifactId>exposed-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>0.38.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.19.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-locations</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-resources</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor_version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.ktor</groupId>
            <artifactId>ktor-server-auth-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${ktor_version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</testSourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlin_version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>${main.class}</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I have been working to fix this for the last few hours, searching the web exhaustively, and this is my last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The dependency `ktor-server-content-negotiation-jvm` for the `ContentNegotiation` plugin is missing in the `pom.xml` file. The artifact name for the `Locations` plugin must have a platform suffix, e.g. `ktor-server-locations-jvm`. The `Authentication` plugin can be imported just fine using your `pom.xml` file.